# How “old” is Odo?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

I am watching the season 2 episode “The Alternate” in which Dr Mora, the scientist who discovered Odo, relays stories about his early years and expresses doubt that Odo was ready to leave.

Is it ever established how long ago Odo was discovered by the scientists?

The only other data points I can think of is that he came to Deep Space 9 5 years before season 2(from “Necessary Evil”), and that the other Alpha Quadrant changeling who visits the station is “older” at ~200 years.

Comment: I don't know his age. But, if we go by his awful, extraordinarily grumpy and unlikable personally, I'd say he's quite old. NOTE: I'm not saying old people generally have unlikable personalities, or anything.

Comment: http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Hundred_Changelings

Comment: @WhitePrime Old people ARE generally grumpy, because *getting old sucks* (ask me how I know.)  But sometimes young people are grumpy by nature, too, so that's why it's hard to tell in Odo's case =P

Comment: @Steve-O Lol. I see : )

Comment: @WhitePrime Yes, you are in fact saying precisely that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It would appear that Odo was sent away from the planet of the Founders at much the same time as Laas (some time in the 22nd Century?), along with [98 other infant changelings](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hundred_Changelings). Odo's vessel was sucked into a previously unknown wormhole just [a few hundreds of lightyears from Dominion space](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/157256/how-far-was-the-wormhole-from-dominion-territory/157425#157425) and then lay dormant in the Denorios Belt where it was discovered by the Bajorans some 170 years later.

There was a line cut from the original [DS9: Emissary](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/402.txt) script which confirms the finding of Odo's ship and which confirms his age.

> **DAX:** (continuing) *.. There have also been twenty-three navigational reports over the years of severe neutrino disturbances in
>   the same area...*
>
> [Pressing another panel...]
>
> **DAX:** (continuing) *And **thirty-two years ago, a vessel of unknown origin appeared there, carrying a single lifeform, a species never
>   encountered before.***

Comment: From http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Chimera_(episode): _Seeing that Odo hasn't tried to find the other Hundred and he's only been taking their form for 30 years, Laas sees that it's still new to Odo._ In terms of his development, it seems Odo is about 30, although he has been alive much longer.